# Public smart contract that calls Private contract API

Tags: private-blockchain, contract-invocation, quorum

In a private blockchain (e.g, quorum), assume that I have a peer X and peer Y. X has a private smart contract (A) and Y has a public smart contract B.

Assume that A provides an API for Y in order to invoke a view function Fa from his private smart contract (Fa takes an address as a parameter and return true if the address exists is a table internal to the private smart contract (A)).

Assume that Y invokes a function Fb from his public smart contract that calls the provided API to get the returned value (true or false) for a given address.

I want to know if such a scenario is possible and if possible the details of how such a transaction is made (transaction lifecycle and how and when the function Fa is invoked)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89050/discussion-on-question-by-a-gh-public-smart-contract-that-calls-private-contract).

Answer (score 2):

No.

Quorum has a shared/public state and each node maintains a private state. The private state is only updated by private transactions tagged with `privateFor`. This includes contract deployment transactions that create contracts with bytecode known only to the included parties.

*To my knowledge*, there is no way to directly connect a public transaction with a private contract or otherwise cross that boundary. How would other nodes verify the public transactions without knowledge of private bytecode that played a role?

In terms of a practical approach, you might consider "trusted" nodes that listen to event logs (public and private contracts they are privy to) and inject transactions on the other side in a predictable and auditable fashion. You would have to work out the inputs/outputs and assurances provided by your bridge.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is correct. In terms of Quorum, a private smart contract may read a function of a public smart contract, but not other way around. Private contract may not update a state of public smart contract either.

A dapp / API may be built to service such function, but this is not the same as accessing data via smart contracts.